# use javascript/jquery/PHP to call automatically img link 1.jpg, 1.1.jpg, 1.2.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg ... instead call them in each links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, image

I'm using fancybox and to display my gallery i call all images like that

```
<a class="fancyboxgallerybook1" data-fancybox-group="book1" href="http://www.domaine.com/wp-content/uploads/books/1-latest/1.jpg" title="">

<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook1" src="http://www.domaine.com/wp-content/uploads/books/1-latest/01.jpg" alt=""/>

</a>

<a class="fancyboxgallerybook1" data-fancybox-group="book1" href="http://www.domaine.com/wp-content/uploads/books/1-latest/2.jpg" title="">

<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook1" src="http://www.domaine.com/wp-content/uploads/books/1-latest/02.jpg" alt=""/>

</a>


...
```

Can I use javascript, jquery, php ... in my page to call images present in my folder in ascending order, I mean: **1.jpg, 1.1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.1.jpg, 4.2.jpg, ...** automatically without to set the numbers in each links like that

```
<a class="fancyboxgallerybook1" data-fancybox-group="book1" href="http://www.domaine.com/wp-content/uploads/books/1-latest/" title="">

<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook1" src="http://www.domaine.com/wp-content/uploads/books/1-latest/" alt=""/>

</a>

<a class="fancyboxgallerybook1" data-fancybox-group="book1" href="http://www.domaine.com/wp-content/uploads/books/1-latest/" title="">

<img class="fancyboxthumbnailsgallerybook1" src="http://www.domaine.com/wp-content/uploads/books/1-latest/" alt=""/>

</a>


...
```

**UPDATE QUESTION**

Can I generate my gallery directly with PHP without changing my structur ?

Comment: No, clientside javascript has no access to the folders, but you can have PHP look in the folders and output the images in Wordpress instead.

Comment: I can use php  if it's needed, but how PHP can search for images in wordpress folder ? at this time i'm using a plugin to upload images in folders, and I call them in my page by their name !! can i call all images from this folder without mention a number in my link with PHP ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing, the only thing I can tell you is that clientside javascript has no access to the filesystem, and can't check for files in a folder. I assume the files are on the server, and PHP runs on the server and can indeed check folders, and Wordpress is written in PHP, so I assume there's a way to do this.

Comment: you totally right, your logic is right. If I can give you more details of my situation, if you check my question, I'm using fancybox and call my images by name, can I call images without use a name with PHP ? note that all my images in folders are 1.jpg, 1.2.jpg, 2.jpg .... any images with name like sky.jpg, rain.jpg .... I'm only using numbers

Comment: @adeneo perhaps is better question, can I generate my gallery directly with PHP ?

Comment: You probably can, I've retagged the question to "PHP", maybe someone has a PHP answer for you

Comment: thank you mister @adeneo